# Is it undesirable for authentication to require decrypting a ciphertext?

Tags: block-cipher, authentication, mac, authenticated-encryption, modes-of-operation

A couple years ago, I devised some primitives for block ciphers and block cipher modes of operation; I was partly inspired by CAESAR. What these designs all had in common is that the encryption/decryption process would produce a bit string $T_i$ for each block and all of these bit strings would be combined together to make the authentication tag $T$.

Today I remembered some of the reasons why encrypt-then-MAC is preferred over other authentication methods, so now I'd like to know if the authenticated encryption schene described above is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like [OCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCB_mode). OCB and similar schemes are fine. Security bounds are usually a little weaker than non-integrated Encrypt then MAC(EtM) constructions but not enough to matter.

But creating your own? OCB-like constructions are subtle and can break very very badly. [OCB2 was shown to be completely insecure for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCB_mode#Attacks). EtM constructions are pretty easy to get right. If building your own EtM construction is like cutting down a tree, creating an OCB-like construction would be juggling running chainsaws.

### Side channel attacks

If side channel attacks are a concern, then EtM constructions help in that decryption keys are never touched until the authentication tag is checked. If the attacker is mounting a side channel attack to recover the encryption keys that adds an additional inconvenience (need to recover the MAC key first).

Comment: Note that OCB and current standardised/popular schemes (e.g. AES-GCM, ChaCha20-Poly1305) have a design flaw in that they're [not committing](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/1260). This causes [vulnerabilities](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1456) in [certain](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/016) scenarios like for [messaging apps](https://breakingthe3ma.app/). Sponge-based constructions are a simple fix for this problem assuming they have a large enough tag, like [AEGIS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-aegis-aead). Encrypt-then-MAC done properly also solves this problem.

Comment: I don't know if it's OCB-like or not. I'm pretty sure it's more general than OCB. What I mean is is it undesirable for the same reasons MAC-then-encrypt or encrypt-and-MAC are? Like, how the decrypted data is vulnerable to handling without authentication.